# For loop skipping index 0 when user's input and print in Java

Tags: java, arrays

For example, I entered a size of 3 Students. It skips index 0 in the console also in printing.

[Please refer to this image, I have a sample size of 3 students and its output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pLIB.png)

I don't have the slightest idea of why it skips index 0? Thanks for the help!

```html
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class string{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter Student Size: ");
        int studentSize = console.nextInt();
        String [] arrName = new String[studentSize];

        for (int i=0; i<arrName.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter student name: ");
            String nameString = console.nextLine();
            arrName[i] = nameString;
        }

        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arrName));

        //Closing Braces for Class and Main
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this skip is due to the different behaviour of the `console.nextInt()` and `console.nextLine()` as:

`console.nextInt()` reads the integer value entered, regardless of whether you hit the enter for new-line.

`console.nextLine()` reads the whole line, but as you previously hit enter when you give the size of Array.

`3` was accepted as the size of the Array and when you hit enter it was accepted as the first value for your array which is a blank space or I can say it is referred to as `""`.

Following are the two resolutions for this:

1. Either put a `console.nextLine()` call after each `console.nextInt()` to consume rest of that line including newline
2. Or, even better, read the input through `Scanner.nextLine` and convert your input to the proper format you need. you may convert to an integer using `int studentSize = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine())` method. (Surround it with try-catch)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `console.nextInt()`, this function only reads the int value.So In your code inside the loop  `console.nextLine()` first time  skip the getting input.just puting `console.nextLine()`after`console.nextInt()`
you can solve the problem.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Student Size: ");
        int studentSize = console.nextInt();
        console.nextLine();
        String [] arrName = new String[studentSize];

        for (int i=0; i<arrName.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter student name: ");
            String nameString = console.nextLine();
            arrName[i] = nameString;
        }

        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arrName));

        //Closing Braces for Class and Main

    }
```